# Placeholder wildcard for string in htaccess RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteCond in htaccess:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyzdomain.com$
```

Now I would like to use a placeholder for the string "domain" in xyzdomain.com so that the condition matches with any domain like xyzhome.com, xyztravel.com, xyzshop.com, xyz*.com, etc.

Which placeholder can I use for the string?

Answer (score 12):

It's just a regex. You can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz(.+)\.com$
```

The `(.+)` will match "any character one or more times".

Also note the `\` escaping the `.` in `.com`. `.` is a special wildcard character with regular expressions so you have to escape it when you want to explicitly match `.`.

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great place to learn more about how they work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The link is also very useful!

Comment: @user1205660 If it helped I'd sure appreciate it if you mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Is there a wild card selectory for the TLD domain so I could use it for ,com, .co.uk. .net or .anything?

Comment: @RichardYoung It's just a regular expression so you can match whatever you want. For example, you could do `^xyz(.+)\.(com|co\.uk|net)$` or you could do `^xyz(.+)\..+$`.

Comment: Would I be able to use
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(com|co\.uk|net)$

Comment: @RichardYoung Yes, that will match fine. Keep in mind that `HTTP_HOST` may or may not start with `www.`. I recommend always doing a redirect to `www.` if it doesn't for consistency. Don't know if that will affect your use case though.

Comment: That's what I'm wanting to do. Direct to the www page if it isn't included but some domain names differ and some TLD differ.

Comment: @RichardYoung You should do something like the following. 
Condition should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(?:com|co\.uk|net)$ [NC]` and the following line should have something like `RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=302,L]`. Keep in mind I haven't tested that but I think it should work. It won't add the `www` if another subdomain is explicitly specified but otherwise it will add it. This does depend on you listing out the TLDs though in the regex as shown.

Comment: Is there a way to do an exclusion on it so that while using the wild card there is one condition in there that I want it to exclude?